# Failed to find provider info for com. google.android.gsf.gservices Failed to load maps.Could not contact google servers

Tags: android, google-maps

```
Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings  
Failed to find provider info for com. google.android.gsf.gservices   
Failed to load maps.Could not contact google servers
```

After one night of searching,I have found the reason.

Comment: sorry,just killed the error 
'Failed to load maps.Could not contact google servers'.
'Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings'  
'Failed to find provider info for com. google.android.gsf.gservices'
still show up.

Comment: @MrStrolling - Solutions are always welcome. However, you might want to restructure the above into a "question" (to conform with SO's [Q&A format](http://stackoverflow.com/about/)).  Then post the "answer" separately.

Answer (score 3):

After one night of searching,I have found the reason.

Because the key I got is Google Maps API Key instead of Google Maps Android API Key.

When I obtained the API Key by the Google APIs Console, in the Services,I clicked the switch of Google Maps API V2 instead of Google Maps Android API V2.

So when you have the same problem,please check the key you got by clicking the switch of Google Maps Android API V2.

I hope the above can help you go to bed on time.(the problem made me stay up for the whole night in front of computer)